# Laravel query builder count rows by day SQL db::raw

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've got a Laravel 8 application whereby I need to count the number of total applications for each day and output a count of the data in the most efficient way, for instance, 500 applications on 1st, 1,000 applications on 2nd and so fourth, depending on how many applications there are each day.

I'm using `DB::raw()` to count my rows, however, Laravel's timestamps by default includes the hours, minutes and seconds as part of the date, and so this isn't going to work for me, I need to format the date to exclude this and just contain the day.

My query doesn't seem to be returning anything, and no error either, so I think there's something wrong with my first `DB::raw()`, it doesn't seem to be formatted the `created_at` column at all, what am I missing?

```php
Application::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
           ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT("created_at, %Y-%m-%d")'), DB::raw('count(*) as applications'))
           ->groupBy('created_at')
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupByRaw()

```
Application::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
           ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")'), DB::raw('count(*) as applications'))
           ->groupByRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")')
           ->get();
```

Also, you can use selectRaw() instead of select(DB::raw)

Comment: The error I get with this is: `Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'`

Comment: `created_at` in the DB is the default Laravel format and is: `2021-06-01 09:10:42`

Comment: That's at select, please change to `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")`